# Windows 7 hangs when trying to read USB drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers

I'm having a strange problem with a Sandisk USB drive. When I plug it into the computer, it takes a bit of time for it to even show up as on of the drives under "Computer". When I right click or double click to try to access the properties or explore the contents of the drive, the loading bar shows in windows explorer, but it just hangs. When I try to refresh device manager, or run disk park, or use the windows partition tool, everything hangs as windows 7 tries to do whatever it's doing with the USB drive.

I've tried uninstalling the drivers for the drive through device manager (I think it actually ended up loading at one point for me to have been able to do this), but that didn't work. I also tried uninstalling all my USB drives, but since that prevented me from using my keyboard and mouse, I had to do a system restore. I have the latest drivers from my computer's manufacturer (it's an Acer M3985).

What should I do?

Edit
Plugged it into another computer and formatted it and now it's fine. I don't understand what the problem could have been.

Comment: Get a new drive. This one is likely broken. Can you test it with other PCs?

Comment: Yes, I have had **3** of these sandisks do exactly the same thing. Never again will I buy them. ALL of them are in the bin. Plugging into a new computer was fine, until it was used multiple times on that new computer and then the same issue continued. I also removed the drivers, followed the help section on the sandisk website... Nothing helped. All I will say is, next time a PC can read it, take a copy of the data. I changed make and not had an issue since.

Answer (score 0):

You should always perform a quick format of a problematic mass storage device before you potentially waste your time and money replacing something that may not have a *physical* problem.

As you've seen... a free solution to the logical/formatting problem with this drive was only 20 seconds away!